# How can I draw points in WPF 3D?

Tags: wpf, 3d

WPF's basic unit of representation for 3D is a mesh of triangles.  However, I want to be able to represent points, e.g. for a scatterplot.  What's the best way to do this?

I've been experimenting with the ScreenSpaceLines3D class from the 3DTools package on CodePlex, trying different ways to get it to draw just a single square instead of a full line, but the visual appearance is pretty poor.

[Clarification: I could draw glyphs, as Reed suggests below, but in order to conserve my triangle budget I'd prefer nothing fancy.  I've been trying squares, but I'd prefer something more point-like in appearance.  I wonder if I could determine what the "minimum" possible sized square would be?]

Any suggestions?

-mpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Billboarding (which is what ScreenSpaceLines3D does) is one approach.  Instead of a square, you can make a circle (or hex, etc), which will improve the appearance quite a bit.

Another option is to use a glyph of some form at each point - for example, place a small (coarse) sphere at each point location.

Comment: After some research, billboarding is really the best one can do, so we'll call this the Answer... But like so many things in life, there is no ideal answer for this one at all.  Billboarding doesn't present the perfect point-like appearance I was looking for, and consumes quite a bit of my triangle budget.  *sigh*  -mpg